# Obtener la lista que este contenida entre dos Datos

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

Tengo una Colección de n Cantidad de Objetos, en el cual un campo es booleano, como podría obtener todos los objetos que estén entre dos objetos que tengan el campo en true: EJ:

```
$scope.lista = [
    {d1:false, d2:Hola0},
    {d1:false, d2:Hola1},
    {d1:true,  d2:Hola2},
    {d1:false, d2:Hola3},
    {d1:false, d2:Hola4},
    {d1:false, d2:Hola5},
    {d1:false, d2:Hola6},
    {d1:true,  d2:Hola7},
    {d1:false, d2:Hola8},
    {d1:false, d2:Hola9}]
```

Entones necesito recuperar:

```
{d1:true,  d2:Hola2},
{d1:false, d2:Hola3},
{d1:false, d2:Hola4},
{d1:false, d2:Hola5},
{d1:false, d2:Hola6},
{d1:true,  d2:Hola7}
```

De que manera podria realizarlo ya sea en AngularJS o desde C#.NET .. he pensado realizarlo con un par de validaciones y variables extras en un for, pero busco algo mas estetico, que me recomiendan .. Saludos y Gracias !!

Comment: Y si tiene 3 true?

Comment: eso ya lo tengo resuelto  con evento change en los check

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas lo puedes realizar con `javascript` simple.

aquí un ejemplo:

```js
var Array = [
    {d1:false, d2:"Hola0"},
    {d1:false, d2:"Hola1"},
    {d1:true,  d2:"Hola2"},
    {d1:false, d2:"Hola3"},
    {d1:false, d2:"Hola4"},
    {d1:false, d2:"Hola5"},
    {d1:false, d2:"Hola6"},
    {d1:true,  d2:"Hola7"},
    {d1:false, d2:"Hola8"},
    {d1:false, d2:"Hola9"}],
newArray = [],
isTrue = false;

for (i in Array) {
 if (isTrue) {
  newArray.push(Array[i]);
  if (Array[i].d1)
   break;
 } else {
  isTrue = Array[i].d1;
  if (isTrue)
   newArray.push(Array[i]);
 }
}
console.log(Array);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Eso ya lo se.. Es lo mismo que comente al final de la pregunta.. Busco alguien más elegante.. Pero gracias

Answer (score 0):

No se si es la forma más elegante pero te puede ayudar

Primero filtras los indices de los dos `true` del array de objetos, éstos te servirán como parámetros de inicio y fin en el `slice` que le harás al array `lista`

```
var arrayFiltered = []
var arrayResult = []

for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
  if (lista[i].d1 === true) {
    arrayFiltered.push(i)
  }
}

var arrayResult = lista.slice(arrayFiltered[0], arrayFiltered[1]+1)
```

Comment: andas .. me diste otra idea ... obtene el primero y el ultimo y parasar lo que este desde hasta ellos al nuevo array ..

Answer (score -1):

por lo que veo estas usando angularjs, pero esto lo resuelves muy fácilmente con el metodo "filter" propio de la clase prototype Array de la siguiente manera:

```
var newList = $scope.lista.filter(function(element){
   return item.d1 === true; //returna aqueos items que tienen la propiedad di como true
})
```

te recomiendo visitar para mejor comprencion https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter

Espero que esto te ayude, saludos :)

Comment: Leíste la pregunta????

Comment: Leíste la pregunta???

Comment: Cual pregunta? esta claro que busca una mejor manera filtrar un array de objetos cuya propiedad boleana sea verdadera.

Comment: Te lo explico facil .. tengo 10 datos con todos en false, pongo el dato 2 y  5 en true .. entonces necesito recuperar en un nuevo arreglo el dato 2, 3, 4 y 5 .. reviza el ejemplo de lo que tengo y lo que me deberia regresar

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo tu, es un simple filtro y solo me recuperar el dato  2 y 5 ... no los que estan en medio de ellos ¬¬